# Adding a nonce tag to an inline code block

Tags: tags, js

While it's possible to pass an html element into a JS file declaration using 'with' as in:

```
{% js '/url/here' with { nonce: { nonce } } %}
```

this approach is not available for a JS inline code block for some reason:

```
{% js with { nonce: { nonce } } %} 
  code here 
{% endjs %} //doesn't work
```

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`{% script %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/tags.html#script) tag instead:

```
{% script with { nonce } %}
    code here
{% endscript %}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much. And yes, as you pointed out, 'with { nonce }' is all that's needed to render the variable in the tag.